# Android using scale type as centerCrop on ImageView does nothing

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

I am trying to centerCrop my image but it doesn't seem to work. Here is the layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/bg_block_list"
    tools:context="com.contag.app.fragment.NavDrawerFragment">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rl_drawer_header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_nav_drawer_header"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:background="@drawable/default_profile_pic"
                     />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/bg_user_activity"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="30dp">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_usr_name"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:text="Name"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />

                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_usr_cunt_id"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rl_notification_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/light_blue"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_notification_txt"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:text="@string/notification"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:onClick="onClick"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have shortened the xml for posting here, specially the part which justifies for using a scrollView. What am I doing wrong?

Attached the output I am getting. [image]

Comment: `android:background` -> `android:src`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change below code to :

```
 <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_nav_drawer_header"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:background="@drawable/default_profile_pic"
                     />
```

TO :

```
<ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_nav_drawer_header"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/default_profile_pic"
                     />
```

As per your requirement you have to set  image view's `width and height as wrap_content`
and `src` instead of `background` .